# Tap responsiveness

Tags: cordova, touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I've developed an cordova application and I've used several techniques on handling touch events including the fastclick library. The events register but not 100% of the time.

My issue is with how sometimes a button fails to trigger its action. When pressing to near its edges, when tapping it to fast, or that sometimes it just feels slower then a native button.

Is this just just one of the drawbacks of using the webview or is there a way to make tap events feel truly native-like in cordova?